# The best way to find index of point in nd array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python3 and numpy. I have an nd array like:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6]])
```

I want to find position of point for example [3,4]. I am using this

```
idP = [id for id in range(len(arr)) if (arr[id] == [3,4]).all()]
```

what is the best way to do this

Comment: are you looking for `np.flatnonzero((arr == [3,4]).all(axis=1))` or `np.where((arr == [3,4]).all(axis=1))[0]`

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "best", you mean most idiomatic and fastest, right?

Comment: @enke this is realy helpfull if you have more then one same points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```py
arr.tolist().index([3,4])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this is good solution if yoy have only one point

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by:

```
(arr == [3, 4]).all(-1).nonzero()[0]
```

or by using `np.isin`:

```
np.isin(arr, [3, 4]).all(1).nonzero()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be converting you numpy array into a python list

```
arr.tolist().index([3,4])
>>> 1
```